# Is there any Instagram Direct Messages RESTful type API?

Tags: instagram-api, restful-url, get-request

I am working in an messaging app, I need to **implement Instagram direct messaging**, but i cant able to find any official direct message API support. Is there any private API which can provide direct messaging support. Please let me know. I need some kind of RESTful API support with GET or POST requests.

[This private API not providing direct message support](https://www.npmjs.com/package/instagram-private-api)

Answer (score 1):

Currently, the official Instagram API documentation does not support any endpoint to make requests and send Direct Messages.

If you would like to check out more detailed information about the supported requests, you may read this official link for developers: https://www.instagram.com/developer/endpoints/

I hope it helps you.

Comment: Thanks for your efforts @Kevi Augusto